# How can I detect if user has successfully alerted a thing (I'm making an XSS game)

Tags: javascript, php, html, xss

The page just echoes the user input using GET. I have no idea on what concept to apply to detect if the user has alerted something

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
include [example] of your code,
 provide more information about the problem: 
results
,
 and anything else that can help us solve your problem.
See [ask]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would probably be to replace the `alert` method with your own.

```js
const log = [];

alert = function(alert) {
  return (value) => {
    log.push(value);
    alert(value);
  };
}(alert);

alert("Hello!");
console.log(log);
```